Exact solution to this integral $\int_a^b \frac{1}{u}\frac{(w+z_2 u)^{\frac{z_2}{z_1+z_2}}}{(w+z_1 u)^{\frac{z_1}{z_1+z_2}}} du$
I have a Fokker-Planck equation
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}\label{FP1dim}
     \partial_{\tau} f(X,\tau) = -\partial_X v(X) f(X,\tau) + \frac{1}{2} \partial_{X}^2 D(X) f(X,\tau)
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
with absorbing boundaries at $X=0$ and $X=1$ and specific (but lenghty) $v$, $D$. The probability of being absorped at 1 when starting at $X_0$ can be calculated as
\begin{align}
    \pi_1(X_0)= \frac{\int_{0}^{X_0} \nu(y)dy}{\int_0^1 \nu(y) dy}
\end{align}
with
\begin{equation*}
    \nu(y) = \exp \left( 2\int_0^y \frac{v(z)}{D(z)}dz \right).
\end{equation*}
Now I managed to calculate
\begin{align}
\nu(y) = C \frac{1}{y}\frac{(w+z_2 y)^{\frac{z_2}{z_2-z_1}}}{(w+z_1 y)^{\frac{z_1}{z_2-z_1}}}
\end{align}
where $0<z_1<z_2<1$, $w>0$ and $C$ is some constant. I am stuck with the resulting integral over $\nu$. Wolframalpha (thanks https://math.stackexchange.com/users/875158/friendlyneighborhoodengineer) gives a lenghty antiderivative with a hypergeometric series in two variables, but I wonder wheter something can be inferred nonetheless.

Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about how to ask a good question.

I didn't manage to solve this integral. However, wolfram can solve this (though you will have to input the boundaries). Check the section Alternate form of the integral. Link: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B1%2Cu%5DDivide%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29w%2BSubscript%5Bz%2C2%5Du%5C%2841%29%2CDivide%5BSubscript%5Bz%2C2%5D%2CSubscript%5Bz%2C1%5D%2BSubscript%5Bz%2C2%5D%5D%5D%2CPower%5B%5C%2840%29w%2BSubscript%5Bz%2C1%5Du%5C%2841%29%2CDivide%5BSubscript%5Bz%2C1%5D%2CSubscript%5Bz%2C1%5D%2BSubscript%5Bz%2C2%5D%5D%5D%5D%2Cu%5D
